# eBay trading API <ShippingDetails> not showing in response

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I am currently testing the `GetOrders` call for the eBay trading API using PHP XML.

I am trying to pull tracking data for my orders, but it seems that the response doesn't contain any tracking info.

By following [this page](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/ebay/GetOrders.html#Response.OrderArray.Order.TransactionArray.Transaction.CreatedDate) I expected to find my tracking data here:

```
<OrderArray>
  <Order>
   <ShippingDetails>
    <ShipmentTrackingDetails>
       <ShipmentTrackingNumber> <MY_TRACKING_NUMBER> </ShipmentTrackingNumber>
    </ShipmentTrackingDetails>
   </ShippingDetails>
  </Order>    
</OrderArray>
```

However, my response does not contain the above data.
My xml request is formated like this:

```
<GetOrdersRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
 <RequesterCredentials><eBayAuthToken> blah blah </eBayAuthToken></RequesterCredentials>
 <DetailLevel>ReturnAll</DetailLevel>
 <NumberOfDays>30</NumberOfDays>
 <OrderRole>Seller</OrderRole>
 <OrderStatus>Completed</OrderStatus>
</GetOrdersRequest>
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, the tracking info has been moved to within the transaction array.